# Current menu item highlights wrong

Tags: customization, menus, navigation

The menu is with different types of links equipped. The first is a link to a subsite. The other is with to an anchor link.

The problem is that the anchorlink is highlighted on the homesite. If I don't use a absolut link the highlight is fixed but if I am on an other site the links dosen't work.

So is there a way to fix the Problem?
I am also a little bit confused that I don't found an answer.
Maybe I searched wrong. Please send me an documentation or an answer.

Comment: What do you mean 'highlighted'? Do you mean it has the [`visited` CSS style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited)? You can add some CSS to change how that's displayed if you want.

Comment: I want it will displayed right. At the moment the anchor points will displayed as visited and I don't want this. I want that the right link is activ

Comment: It will be displayed as visited if you have visited it. The best you can probably do is to write some CSS for the link so that the visited style matches the normal style. (It might also be possible to write some script to remove the visited style, but I've never tried that.)